# Why the inconsistency between Scifi and Music Communities here on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

I've seen posts to the Scifi community asking for help identifying author and title for stories based on very scant details.

But similar posts on the Music community aren't permitted. Why is this? There's a question I'd like to ask but I'm not allowed.

Comment: Dom's answer is a good one, but note also that there are several past discussions about this here on Meta if you want to see all of the reasoning.  And to emphasize -- we get to set our scope independent of any other site.

Comment: There is currently some controversy over at Movies and TV about identification, although it looks like they will keep allowing such questions. In any case, note that neither SF&F nor Movies & TV are about **creating** the media they discuss. Music Theory and Practice has a primary focus on questions related to writing music, performing music, and learning how to write and perform music, with some analysis on the side. This site is not a fandom. It's closer to the Server Fault model, where this is about work, not play.

Answer (score 22):

This is because Music SE is geared towards people who create, practice, and study music, not for the general music consumer. The questions don't match the audience we have here. Not all SEs handle the same type of question the same way as the scope and the target audience for each is very different .

There is a [Music Fan Stack Exchange site](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) that was made to bridge this gap.

Answer (score 15):

One way to look at the difference is that this isn't exactly "the Music community" of Stack Exchange. That's Music Fans. This is more like "the **musician** community" of Stack Exchange.

Imagine if [World Building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) allowed identification questions. It would not fit in with that site at all. World Building is in many ways the writer's community on Stack Exchange, and SF&F and Movies and TV are both fan-centered communities, again, like Music Fans for music.